# different between windows authentication , form authentication and trusted claim provided authentication

Tags: sharepoint-2013

What is different between windows authentication , form authentication and trusted claim provided authentication. I know the what are they but how its work in SharePoint I want to know.

Few quest are

When I select authentication as form authentication can user can login using SharePoint login credential or they want to login use a out of the active dir credential